# Angular 12 Update - CSS loading delay on angular SSR

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-universal, angular12

I have recently updated my angular app version 11 to 12. also using SSR. previously it was working perfectly.
now on SSR build it's loading CSS a bit late & display raw HTML first & after some time loads the CSS.
I tried changing the sequence of the CSS file from angular.json but nothing worked.

screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have same issue but not found solution :(

Comment: @dakshita Sharma I faced the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Comment: @Poonkodi you also need to update *@nguniversal* version

Comment: This is my universal version -"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^12.1.0",